# Something in my bashrc file causing bash: command not found?

Tags: bash

When I open up a new shell I get:

```
Last login: Sun Mar 23 10:14:46 on ttys000

-bash:  : command not found
```

I'm not totally sure how to figure out what's going on there, as its not totally clear which command its talking about.

Is it likely something in the .bashrc file?

```
HISTSIZE=10000
HISTFILESIZE=20000

export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxCxDxBxegedabagacad
export PS1="\[\e[01;32m\]\h \[\e[01;34m\]\W \$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[01;34m\]$\[\e[00m\] "

export PYTHONSTARTUP=/Users/JimShook/.pythonstartup
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

function parse_git_dirty {
    [[ $(git status 2> /dev/null | tail -n1) != "nothing to commit (working directory clean)" ]] && echo "*"
}

function parse_git_branch {
    git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e "s/* \(.*\)/[\1$(parse_git_dirty)]/"
}

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
```

Or maybe the bash_profile?

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi


[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Any thoughts are helpful.

Comment: Those look OK. You might also check/post virtualenvwrapper.sh which is sourced. One way to trouble-shoot a shell is to run:  bash -xv <file> to get detailed output. Might be worth a try.

Comment: It's possible your `.bashrc` has acquired DOS line endings; the "blank" line 3 appears to bash to consist of a single carriage return, which would be the command that isn't found (`bash` doesn't treat carriage returns as whitespace).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things to check - as suggested above:

- anything changed recently?  if so, start there... (added new line/command/sourced file?)
- look for 'control codes' in the your file(s)

Try:

```
cat -v ~/.bashrc ## look for '^M' or other special chars - remove if present

bash -n ~/.bashrc ## try the 'sourced files' separately
```

If using VI, some thing to try after opening the file:

- :syntax off ## turn off colors - may be easier to see 'hidden' codes
- :set list ## control codes may be visible